# How to set the order of the query as descending

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting, quantity, best-seller, product-sorting

I have created a query that would allow me to sort my products based on the quantity they have been ordered. But when I print the query, the quantity ordered is coming in Ascending order. I want to make it work in descending order. The query is as below

```
$toDate =  date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime('tomorrow') - 1);
$fromDate = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime("-1 months"));
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoi' => $this
->getTable('sales/order_item')),
 "e.entity_id = sfoi.product_id AND sfoi.created_at BETWEEN 
 '{$fromDate}' AND '{$toDate}'",                 
array('qty_ordered' => 'SUM(sfoi.qty_ordered)'))
            ->group('e.entity_id')                   
            ->order("qty_ordered {$dir}");        
            return $this;
```

Can anyone kindly let me know how to do this? I just want to change the order of "**qty_ordered**" From ASC to DESC

Answer (score 0):

The query is not executed inside this function, so maybe the order is changed somewhere after. Anyway, you should debug the SQL by adding a log before the return, like:

```
Mage::log($this->getSelect()->__toString(), null, 'mydebug.log');
```

so you can check the exact syntax at this point. You should copy the logged string in your SQL editor to check if everything is fine.
You can check if *$dir == 'DESC'*: maybe it is not. If the executed query from the log is ok, it means that the select is reordered somewhere after this block.